# awk how to print the last value of a counter?

Tags: awk

I have a file with some lines starting with >

I want to count the number of such lines per file.

```
awk '{if(/>/){count += 1}{print count}}' file.text
1
1
2
2
```

Obviously here I just want the last "2". Basically I want awk to print the last value of count. It seems to me that should be easy to accomplish but can't find how.

I know there are solutions such as grep -c that would do the job but I am curious to have the awk version.

Thank you

EDIT: I have tried this

```
awk '{if(/>/){count += 1}END{print count}}' Scaffold_1_8558356-8558657.fa_transcripts.combined.filtered.fas
awk: cmd. line:1: {if(/>/){count += 1}END{print count}}
awk: cmd. line:1:                     ^ syntax error
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your tried code try following once.

```
awk '{if(/>/){count += 1}} END{print count+0}' file.text
```

OR you could shorten above to:

```
awk '/>/{count++} END{print count+0}' file.text
```

Comment: Hello, yes I did, sorry I should have mentionned it, I am editing the original question.

Comment: @Axzd, try this one, this one should work, you haven't closed it properly.

Comment: Ahhhh yes I saw I did not properly used the "}"
Waw so cool to have an answer so fast, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Beware, you want to

> I have a file with some lines starting with > I want to count the
> number of such lines per file.

but you are asking AWK to check

`if(/>/)`...

which will be true for `>` *anywhere* in line, for example if `file.txt` content is:

```
abc > def
ghi > jkl
mno > prs
```

then

```
awk '{if(/>/){print $0}}' file.txt
```

output

```
abc > def
ghi > jkl
mno > prs
```

You might limit to detecting only at start of line using `^` for example use `'{if(/^>/){print $0}}'` to print only lines which starts with `>`.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*